# can some one help me how to use IList in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm am trying to test wcf method in C#. method return type is ilist. I need to catch that returned data in to an ilist and then i have to retrive each item from ilist. can some one send me a sample code how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to just iterate over an IList if that is what you're asking.

```
foreach(var item in MethodThatReturnsIList())
{
   // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some template code. I don't know what the generic type that is being returned, so I put place holders for it.

```
IList<type of result> list = data.ReturnIList();
foreach(var item in list)
{
   //do stuff with the item
}
```